# in this example, why do I get error in the variable scope?

Tags: c#, scope

I have been doing some examples in C# using VS2008.

The example is the next:

```
    class Program{

        delegate double ProcessDelegate(double param1, double param2);

        static double Multiply(double param1, double param2){
            return param1 * param2;
        }

        static double Divide(double param1, double param2){
            return param1 / param2;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args){
            ProcessDelegate process;    
            char operacion;

            Console.WriteLine("introduzca 2 nros separados por coma: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int commaPos = input.IndexOf(',');

            double param1 = Convert.ToDouble(input.Substring(0, commaPos));
            double param2 = Convert.ToDouble(input.Substring(commaPos+1, input.Length - commaPos - 1));

            Console.WriteLine("Introudzca M para Multiplicar o D para dividir: ");
            do{
                operacion = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            }while (operacion != 'M' && operacion != 'D' && operacion != 'm' && operacion != 'd');

            switch (operacion){
                case 'D':
                    process = new ProcessDelegate(Divide);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", process(param1, param2));        
                    break;

                case 'M':
                    process = new ProcessDelegate(Multiply);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", process(param1, param2));
                   break;
            }//fin switch()

            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", process(param1, param2));
        }//fin Main()
    }//fin Class
```

My doubt is why the WriteLine() sentence outside of the switch section doesn't work if the process varible is declared inside the Main() section?

NOTE: The wirteLine() sentences works fine inside switch section!

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is not that the variable is out of *scope*, its that it's not guaranteed to be *assigned to*.

You could easily fix the error (though expose yourself to a a runtime exception) by just changing the declaration to:

```
ProcessDelegate process = null;
```

Changing the switch to have a `default` case that *also* assigns the delegate *could* fix it, though the compiler can have issues with complex enough code paths when it comes to stuff like this.

Basically, the compiler is delivering a helpful error saying there is a chance of you using an unassigned variable. Assign it to a reasonable value in case the subsequent code isn't run, and you'll be fine.